# How do I stop video autoplay in Firefox 37?

Tags: html, video, tags, autoplay

I need the controls, but don't want the video to autoplay.
The code below, doesn't work.

```
    <video  id="Video1" poster="assets/img/bg-header.jpg"  autoplay="false" 
    controls autostart="false">
```

Thanks,
Sabin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html5 videos don't autoplay by default.

Remove *autoplay="false"*.

[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/furitafovo/2/edit?html,output)

Comment: The video autoplayed when I added the "controls" attribute. I thought I used all combinations.
Thanks, that did it.